# What is the geometric formula of CaI2 and AlCl3

Tags: molecular-structure

Well, I think $\ce{CaI2}$ is the same as $\ce{BeH2}$ and $\ce{AlCl3}$ the same as $\ce{NH3}$, but I'm not sure since $\ce{I}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ have their own pair electrons and I don't know if this affects the structure...

Comment: Central atoms/cations are affecting geometry stronger than atoms they are connected with.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{CaI2}$ is mostly ionic in the solid and aqueous phases.  In the gas phases it is a linear molecule.  See [Ionic or covalent? Can some first hints be derived from the solid state
structures of alkaline earth metal halide adducts?](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2002/ce/b201975m)

$\ce{AlCl3}$ has an octaheral structure in the solid phase.

In the liquid phase:

[image]

Trigonal planar monomers also exist at high temperature.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_chloride